# Gta online access help

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

It keeps telling me my profile does not have permission to access GTA online. I have tried resetting my console, I've tried going to permission settings and making sure everything was right there also.

Comment: What console are you playing on?  Do you pay for Xbox Live Gold or PS+ (depending on your console)?

Answer (score 1):

Were you ever banned? Do you not have Xbox Gold or Playstation +?
If one of these are yes, the answer is. Wait 'till you get unbanned, or for the second one, buy a subscription.